# MySQL NDB Cluster

Tags: mysql, database, ndb

I have a MySQL NDB Cluster with the following topology:

1. app node as NDB Manager
2. mysql1 & mysql2 as replica nodes

And my MySQL NDB Clusterd is already running well and the replicas have also been successfully run. my question is how do I connect my application to my NDB Cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have mysql1 running both a ndbmtd process and a mysqld process you can simply start a MySQL client and connect it to any of the MySQL Servers and start using the database.